# AutoSSH occasionally running into: "channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed" until tunnel is restarted

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm running an autossh script using upstart for ssh tunneling / port forwarding  to my postgresql database. It that looks like this:

```
# Remote server role: database-master
# Remote hostname:    srv-08.aa.com
# Local/remote port:  5432

# autossh startup Script http://www.async.fi/2013/07/autossh-with-ubuntu-upstart/

description "autossh tunnel for role database-master to srv-08.aa.com:5432"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 5 60 # respawn max 5 times in 60 seconds

exec autossh \
  -M 0 \
  -N \
  -L 5432:localhost:5432 \
  -o "ServerAliveInterval=60" \
  -o "ServerAliveCountMax=3" \
  -o "BatchMode=yes" \
  -i /home/the_user/.ssh/id_rsa \
  the_user@srv-08.aa.com
```

I general the forwarding works well. However sometimes, e.g. when the remote server has restarted the postgresql service, it happens that the tunnel becomes useless (cannot connect through it) and in the `/var/log/upstart/autossh-master-db-tunnel.log` I'm seeing the following error being emitted:

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

This continues until I do a `sudo restart autossh-master-db-tunnel` then everything works again.

What is wrong, and how can I fix it? Or at a beginning get more clever about it?